# Prometheus Alert Manager Configure Notification Title URL

Tags: prometheus

In Prometheus Alert Managers Slack Notifications, the default title includes a clickable url link that goes to: `http://app:9093/#/alerts?receiver=<my_receiver_name>`

How do I configure the `http://app` so that it can be `http://myserver`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks to me like that link is generated by this [Go template](https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/blob/d5f0d1773f7d1c325802e1ea4bd77fc8b617aca1/template/default.tmpl#L2):

```
{{ define "__alertmanagerURL" }}{{ .ExternalURL }}/#/alerts?receiver={{ .Receiver }}{{ end }}
```

Which suggests that you should set `--web.external-url=http://myserver` (or `-web.external-url=http://myserver` on older releases) on the command line when starting alertmanager. The flag doesn't seem to be documented anywhere except the [source code](https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/blob/0dfdda3074fa2d19c22dddba42e624078fadfeaf/cmd/alertmanager/main.go#L84).

**UPDATE**: Newer releases of alermtmanager require two hyphens rather than one. Updating this accordingly for people finding this via search.

Comment: Thank you so much! I would not have dug through source code to figure that out. The same command line option exists for Prometheus too which was my related question. Thanks!